# Using Metasploit on Kali to attack a Linux machine

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

Whats wrong with my exploit? I'm trying to attack a Linux machine using Kali. I cannot seem to get the meterpreter session started.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your entire desktop. If needing to show the text, use copy/paste and use the code formatting tool. If you need a screenshot, only include the relevant parts.

Answer (score 2):

You say you are trying to attack a linux machine, but both your payload and exploit are targetting windows.

Comment: Thank you I didn’t understand that my payload are for a windows machine this not working.